# How to read a csv with pandas to create a matrix composed by 3 column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, csv

I  use in my code this declaration to create a film tab. But, how can I create the same using a .csv with the same columns? To be more clear, I have a .csv file with a tab in which are present columns with this data: " 'Film1_name', 'sequel', 6, date, available". How can I read this .csv to have the equivalent of the code written below? Thank you.

```
Films=(
        ['Film1_name', 'sequel', 6, date, available],
        ['Film2_name', 'sequel', 1, date, not available],
        ['Film3_name', 'sequel', 2, date, available],
        
    )
```

In the .csv file data are presented (with no column names) as:

```
Film1_name |sequel | 6 |date| available   
Film2_name |sequel | 1 |date| not available
Film3_name |sequel | 2 |date| available
```

I want to extract columns because after I want to execute a for cycle as:

for j in self.Films:

```
Film_principal= j[0]
Possible_sequel = j[1]
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use read_csv from pandas library
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv

Comment: I know how to read a .csv file but I'd like to know ho to create the equivalent of the code I shown, thank you

Answer (score 0):

this give me only the last value of the column film....how could I have the entire column with the names of Films_principal ?

```
films=filmes_view.to_numpy()

print(films)

for j in films:

    Film_principal=j[0]
```